# Create several snaps from one source directory

Tags: snapcraft, snap

[Go applications](https://snapcraft.io/docs/go-applications) guide for building snaps recommends to create the file `snapcraft.yaml` in the root directory of the project to build a snap.

I want to build several snaps for sub-packages of my source directory, with all snaps sources placed into the root directory of my project. How? (I ask because I cannot place several files with the same name `snapcraft.yaml` into the same directory.)